# My Graph is not updating and I cannot figure out why

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to create a graph based on data from a MySQL database.  I have print statements in the code that show the dataframe is there and has some data.

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc, Input, Output, callback, ctx, 
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sq
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from .utils import getActionCounts,ThroughPut, Graph_Throughput
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import json
from datetime import datetime
import dash_mantine_components as dmc

connection = sq.create_engine(f'mysql://{username}:{password}@{hostname}/{table_name}')

minmax_query = '''
SELECT 
    "from", 
    "to", 
    MIN(START_DATETIME) AS MinDate, 
    MAX(START_DATETIME) AS MaxDate 
FROM 
    schema.TableName
GROUP BY 
    "from", 
    "to";
'''


# Data loading
dates = pd.read_sql(minmax_query,con=connection)
unit_type = ['Unit1', 'Unit2', 'Unit3','*']
dates['MinDate']=pd.to_datetime(dates['MinDate'])
dates['MaxDate']=pd.to_datetime(dates['MaxDate'])

layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dcc.RadioItems(
                options=['Date','TotalTestsRun','Tests Passed','Yield'],                
                value = 'Yield',
                id='tr_radio_btn',
            )
        ],width=2),
        dbc.Col([
            dmc.DateRangePicker(
                id='FPY-DatePicker',
                minDate=min(dates["MinDate"]),
                maxDate=max(dates["MaxDate"]),
                value=[min(dates["MinDate"]),max(dates["MaxDate"])],
                clearable=False,
                #display_format='YYYY-MM-DD'
            ) ]),
            
        dbc.Col([
            dcc.RadioItems(
                options=unit_type,                
                value = '*',
                id='Unit-Type-radio',
            ),
            html.H5('Select Graph Type: '),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='FPY-Graph-Type',
                    options=[{'label': 'Trend', 'value': 'Trend'},
                             {'label': 'Bar', 'value': 'Bar'}],
                    value='Trend',
                    clearable=False,
        ),
        html.Button('Update Graph',id='update-button', n_clicks=0),
            ])
    ]),
    dbc.Row(
        dcc.Graph(id='FPY-df',)
    )   ])

@callback(
    Output(component_id='FPY-df', component_property='figure'),
    [Input('FPY-DatePicker', 'value'),
     Input('Unit-Type-radio','value'),
     Input('tr_radio_btn','value'),
     Input('FPY-Graph-Type','value'), 
     Input('update-button','n_clicks')]
)
def update_text(date,Unit_type,test_data,graph_type, n_clicks):  
    if 'update-button'==ctx.triggered_id:
        start_date,end_date = date
        fig = go.Figure()
        df_sys=pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM schema.TABLE WHERE START_DATETIME >= %s and START_DATETIME<=%s',con=connection,params=(start_date,end_date))
        dict_df_filter = ThroughPut(df_sys,start_date=start_date,end_date=end_date,UnitType=Unit_type)
        print(type(dict_df_filter['bench']))
        fig = Graph_Throughput(df=dict_df_filter['bench'],test_data=test_data,graph_type=graph_type,Unit=Unit_type,fig=fig)
        print(type(fig))
        return fig
    else:
        return None
```

and the Graph_Throughput function is:

```
def Graph_Throughput(df:pd.DataFrame,test_data:str,Unit_type:str, graph_type:str ,fig:go.Figure):
    print(df.head())
    print(test_data)
    print(Unit_type)
    print(graph_type)
    if graph_type=='Trend':
        if Unit_type=='*':
            fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df[test_data], mode='lines', name='All Units'))
        else:
            fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df[test_data], mode='lines', name=str(Unit_type+' '+test_data)))
    elif graph_type=='Bar':
        if Unit_type=='*':
            fig.add_traces(go.Bar(x=df['Date'], y=df[test_data], mode='stacked', name=str('All Units'+test_data)))
        else:
            fig.add_traces(go.Bar(x=df['Date'], y=df[test_data], mode='stacked', name=str(Unit_type+' '+test_data)))
    
    return fig
```

When I try it out in a jupyter notebook ignoring the dash components everything seems to work fine. And if I check the callback graph, then it confirms there is no data shown for the graph.

Comment: Could you give a [example]? For example, what are `sq`, `dbc` or`ctx`?

Comment: Updated with imports.  I am going to modify it to be a single page dash app instead of multipage as the multipage part should be irrelevant.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the only one `Input` for `update-button` and all other inputs - `State`?